# Re-run the Python module when any one of the procedures in a workflow is unsuccessful

Tags: python, try-except

My Python module has a workflow of procedures, namely:

```
try:
    Procedure 1
    Procedure 2
    ... ...
    Procedure n
except Exception, ex:
    print "Error. Details:" + "\n" + " %s" % ex
```

The requirement is the whole module should be re-run if any of the procedures as above fails during execution. A procedure is a snippet of codes.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in a while loop like so:

```
while 1:
    try:
        Procedure 1
        Procedure 2
        ... ...
        Procedure n
        break
    except Exception, ex:
        print "Error. Details:" + "\n" + " %s" % ex
```

Or, in other words, you break out of the loop when everything succeeds, and keep going otherwise.

Comment: Thanx @ Elendia. I will give it a go.